# Rounding to a variable number of decimal places in SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to find a way to round a field in SSRS to a dynamic number of decimal places. I know I can format it dynamically, and it may eventually come to that, but many of my users are going to take this report directly to Excel and are going to want to have actual numeric fields.

My t-SQL code includes these declared variables:

```
      NumLong01                 DECIMAL(23,8)
    , NumLongDP01               INTEGER
```

The first set of entries in this table is for headers and rounding parameters. So I add values for these two as:

```
 NULL
,4
```

and then I add the actual table values as:

```
 543210987654321.87654321
,NULL
```

That way I can put a whole series of numbers into the table but they all have to be formatted the same way.

Running this query yields:

[image]

When I go to ReportBuilder, my field has this expression:

`=Fields!NumLong01.Value`

If I want to format a certain number of decimal places, I can just do this:

`=Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,2)` or some such. What I tried to do, though, was to make it dynamic:

`=Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,First(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1"))`

This ended up rounding to 0 decimal places. I subsequently learned--by just using the second half in my field--that this was a NULL value. So I tried Sum instead of First--again, just in my field--and got the 4 that I expected. Great, so now I had my number, and I just put that in as my rounding:

`=Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,Sum(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1"))`

Only problem is, this yields an error. Next I asked myself if maybe it wasn't seeing this as a number for some reason. So i just added it onto my field. No problems. So I really don't know what it's doing. Is it thinking that this field might become so long that it will round to an illegal number of decimals places?

Now, I can do this:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1") = 8,Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,8),IIf(Sum(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1") = 7,Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,7),IIf(Sum(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1") = 6,Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,6),IIf(Sum(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1") = 5,Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,5),IIf(Sum(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1") = 4,Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,4),IIf(Sum(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1") = 3,Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,3),IIf(Sum(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1") = 2,Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,2),IIf(Sum(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1") = 1,Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,1),Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,0)))))))))
```

...and that works. But it seems like such a ridiculous way to go about it.

I'm also comfortable passing only rounded numbers out of t-SQL. But then I run into the problem of showing only a certain number of decimals on the report, because in the number formatting it doesn't allow for a dynamic number of decimal places for some reason.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Subsequent to this post, I tried using "N4" as a formatting, and it actually worked in Excel so far as I can tell. That hasn't always been the case in the past when I've modified other reports, but I don't know why. So if I can make it work like that, I'm satisfied. But I would still be interested to know why my initial rounding approach didn't work as I had hoped.

Comment: New update: still having the same issues in Excel that I used to. With just one line, I had nothing to add up, and so I just added a fixed number like 4 to it, and that gave me a sum. Therefore it must have been a numeric field in Excel, right? Wrong. When I do multiple lines, I get a count (not a sum) in the bottom right-hand corner, and the sum of my numbers is 0. So I'm back to my insane set of IIf's.

Comment: Just a few brief queries before I suggest a solution. Must the decimal places be specified as the first row of your dataset and are you allowed to alter the table structure? Finally, why do you specifically need to have a variable (dynamic) number of decimal places? Is it to avoid 0 padding?

Comment: I can alter the structure as much as I want--I pretty much own this within the company, and even those that may modify this will probably follow my lead, so if that's what needs to happen, I think I can do that pretty easily. The dynamic number of decimal places is so I can reuse fields in my report without having to add on new ones that are formatted differently.

Comment: Perhaps try taking a different whack at getting and referencing that rounding number: Sort the dataset by the rounding value descending, and use an internal parameter that uses that dataset for its default value.  Then use the parameter in your rounding functions.

Comment: @DaveX `=Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,First(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1"))` can you be clearer on why that rounded to 0 decimal places? A quick test locally shows it working correctly.

Comment: @DaveX Has the answer solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Just got back here, and this is excellent. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an exhaustive list of ways to accomplish dynamic rounding or number formatting as you can achieve this using custom code in the report or by adapting your dataset's SQL query.

**Using Rounding:**

> The first set of entries in this table is for headers and rounding parameters. That way I can put a whole series of numbers into the table but they all have to be formatted the same way.

To avoid building expressions in your report that require aggregate functions such `First` and `Sum` and generating a blank row that you then have to remove, consider just entering the number of decimal places for every row instead of using a header row. The costs (storage and expression evaluation) are low even if it seems redundant.

This means that instead of using: `=Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,First(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1"))` you can use `=Round(Fields!NumLong01.Value,Fields!NumLongDP01.Value)` either as an *expression* or as a *calculated field* in `DataSet1` or whatever your dataset is called.

**Using Number Formatting:**

> But then I run into the problem of showing only a certain number of decimals on the report, because in the number formatting it doesn't allow for a dynamic number of decimal places for some reason.

You can define custom formatting for the `NumLong01` field in the report and make it dynamic using an expression to build your custom formatting string.

1. Open the Text Box Properties for the `NumLong01` textbox or tablix field
2. Open Number tab and select Custom from the Category list
3. Click the fx button and use the following expression `="0." + StrDup(First(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1"), "0")`

Using your example data, this expression would produce the custom formatting string 0.0000 which changes 543210987654321.87654321 to 543210987654321.8765. For your information, `StrDup` duplicates the specified string X number of times.

In cases where the fractional part of the number is less than the decimal precision required, this formatting string will pad it with 0s. If that's not desired, change the string to be duplicated to `"#"` like so: `StrDup(First(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "DataSet1"), "#")`.

You can also use this method as a *calculated field* in the dataset but *only* if you have removed the header row and are entering the decimal places for every row as mentioned earlier. This is because you can't use the aggregate function in the calculated field expression.

To do this, add a *calculated field* to your dataset with the expression: `=Format(Fields!NumLong01.Value, "0." + StrDup(Fields!NumLongDP01.Value, "0"))`